# Compare ingest-time to generated-time for an IOT Stream

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-suite

I've written a Streaming Analytics query to emit 2 date-time values:  one from my stream and the other the 'ingest' date-time into Azure IOT / StreamingAnalytics.  My stream's value is in UTC, but I'm finding that the 'ingest' date-time is offset from 1/1/1970, rather than Utc.Now.

This is my Streaming Analytics query:

`SELECT
    deviceId
    ,System.Timestamp as IngestTimeUTC
    ,date as GenerateTimeUTC
INTO
    [YourOutputAlias]
FROM
    MyDevice`

Sample output:
`DEVICEID ... INGESTTIME ... GENERATEDTIMEUTC`
`"myFirstDevice" ... "1970-01-01T12:01:01.0010000Z"..."2016-11-18T15:25:54.5660000Z"`

How can I normalize ingest-time to UTC for 'today' ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my above query does work as desired.  I neglected to mention that I had been observing the output via the 'Test' option within the Azure Streaming Analytics portal.  When I saved everything and actually ran the job ... I get the `IngestTimeUTC` data normalized in the proper way -- to UTC for 'today' as desired.

So ... the 'test' mechanism does have this inherent behavior with regard to `System.Timestamp`.